# TypeError while trying to join two text files side by side

Tags: python, zip, typeerror

I am trying to join multiple text files together using the zip function but I keep getting the error, `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, generator found`

This is my code,

```
filepaths = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']
with open('op.txt', 'w') as f:
    temp = zip(*[open(fpath for fpath in filepaths)])
    for lines in temp:
        outfile.write('\t'.join(line.strip() for line in lines) + '\n')
```

Please Help me with this error, I am new to scripting with zip & python

Comment: I think you want `[open(fpath) for fpath in filepaths]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to open each file, not the generator. Did you also mean to use `f.write` instead of `outfile.write`?

This worked for me:

```
filepaths = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']
with open('op.txt', 'w') as f:
    temp = zip(*[open(fpath) for fpath in filepaths])
    for lines in temp:
        f.write('\t'.join(line.strip() for line in lines) + '\n')
```

Also note that this will only print the lines up to the length of the shortest file as this is how `zip` behaves. If the files vary in length and you'd like to see all additional lines, you'll need a different strategy, like this:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

filepaths = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']
with open('op.txt', 'w') as f:
    temp = izip_longest(*[open(fpath) for fpath in filepaths])
    for lines in temp:
        f.write('\t'.join(line.strip() for line in lines if line) + '\n')
```